# Excel select first value belong to one name

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, lookup, countif

I need get first value which belong to one fiscal week and the others have zero. I have `IF(COUNTIF(B2:B40,B2)>1,IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,C2,0),"")`.
But I also want the same in the same cell for another person.

`A           B               C   D    E
An Khaly    August Week 32  40  40  40
An Khaly    August Week 32  40  0   0
An Khaly    August Week 32  40  0   0
An Khaly    August Week 32  40  0   0
An Khaly    August Week 32  40  0   0
An Khaly    August Week 33  40  40  40
An Khaly    August Week 34  40  40  40
An Khaly    August Week 34  40  0   0
An Khaly    August Week 34  40  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 31  40  40  40
Zita Pork   August Week 31  40  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 31  40  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 31  40  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 31  40  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 32  20  0   20
Zita Pork   August Week 32  20  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 32  20  0   0
Zita Pork   August Week 33  20  0   20
Zita Pork   August Week 33  20  0   0`

My problem is, that my formula works only for one person (column D) but I need to work for all name with the same fiscal week (column E).
Can anybody please help?
Thx

Comment: In which column do you set this formula? Could you state what you want in words?

Comment: the formula is used in column D. Column E is what I need.

Comment: No, I don't have the column E. I just wrote it here as example what have to be my results. I have table with more then 3000 rows and with column A,B,C. I creates column D with formula "IF(COUNTIF(B2:B40,B2)>1,IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,C2,0),"")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one column between B and C so that Column C will shift to Column D and write formula in C2

> =A2&B2

Now you can write in cell E2

> =IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)=1,D2,"")